# ansible nmcli for Raspbian 10

Tags: ansible, raspbian

Using Ansible, I am trying to provision a Raspberry Pi just freshly imaged with Raspbian 10.

One of the tasks is to set up the network. I'm trying to use `community.general.nmcli`, but so far without success:

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - name: update and upgrade apt packages
      become: true
      apt:
        upgrade: dist
        update_cache: true

    - name: Install network manager
      become: true
      apt:
        name: network-manager
        state: present

    # see https://gist.github.com/truh/de723a3bc0f837f75d3673ddf101e108 and
    # https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/73816/137489
    - name: Uninstall openresolv and dhcpcd5
      become: true
      apt:
        pkg:
        - openresolve
        - dhcpcd5
        state: absent
        purge: yes

    - name: configure network
      become: true
      community.general.nmcli:
        state: present
        conn_name: my-eth0
        ifname: eth0
        type: ethernet
        ip4: 192.168.1.2/24
        gw4: 192.168.1.1
```

The first three tasks correspond to:

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install network-manager
sudo apt purge openresolv dhcpcd5
```

as recommended by [this gist](https://gist.github.com/truh/de723a3bc0f837f75d3673ddf101e108) and [this discussion](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/73816).

These first 3 tasks allow me to use `nmcli` on the command line (of the RPi).

However, the fourth task (using `community.general.nmcli`) fails:

```
fatal: [192.168.1.2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error: invalid property 'routing-rules': 'routing-rules' not among [method, dns, dns-search, dns-options, dns-priority, addresses, gateway, routes, route-metric, route-table, ignore-auto-routes, ignore-auto-dns, dhcp-client-id, dhcp-timeout, dhcp-send-hostname, dhcp-hostname, dhcp-fqdn, never-default, may-fail, dad-timeout].\n", "name": "my-eth0", "rc": 2}
```

Is there a way to get Ansible's `community.general.nmcli` to work on Raspbian 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to Raspbian using NetworkManager prior to version 1.18, which is when the functionality `routing-rules` [was released](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/blob/a2b26e26d9bbb7eb3bc9f9188e50c38bcb7cc22d/NEWS#L449). It wouldn't otherwise be a problem, however, Ansible `nmcli` module expects that this parameter is there when it attempts to create the interface, but then `nmcli` fails with this weird message.

There's already an open issue for that: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues/3948